# Quick contact badge assignContactFromPhone not working in my application

Tags: android

```
           QuickContactBadge qcb=(QuickContactBadge)findViewById(R.id.quickContactBadge1);
            qcb.assignContactFromEmail("atfata@gmail.com",true);
            qcb.assignContactFromPhone("9994834021",true);  
    qcb.setMode(ContactsContract.QuickContact.MODE_SMALL);
```

In this code contact number cannot be assigned to my contact.please suggest any way possible to save the contact in my application

Comment: It might help if you give more details about what you mean by it "cannot" be assigned. Error information or details about the failure, and if important, any steps you took to diagnose it which ruled things out as the issue.

Comment: @yogi : my answer help u or not if it help you in solving issue then mark it answer and if not then tell me i will remove it.thanks

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя K: itz not working man..

Comment: @yogi : then i'm going to delete it .Thanks so much for feedback.

Comment: This is the documentation for it: https://developer.cisco.com/web/cius-developer/quickcontactbadge

Answer (score 0):

`QuickContact.MODE_SMALL` is not supported by all API's, and apart from that, you are setting the contact twice with `assignContactFromEmail(eml)` and `assignContactFromPhone(phn)`, that could also cause the problem. There is a great example on Google Android docs which explains how to do stuff that you need, here's the link, **go to step 2**:

[QuickContactBadge Docs](http://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/display-contact-badge.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try below code -

```
QuickContactBadge qcb=(QuickContactBadge)findViewById(R.id.quickContactBadge1);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.EMAIL, "email address");
qcb.assignContactFromPhone("9994834021",true, bundle);
```

you can put other things also in bundle like name,primary email etc with proper keys.